# Recording .wav with nodejs causes .wav file to be stretched

Tags: node.js, wav

When I recording using wav's FileWriter
https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav#filewriterpath-optionsit my .wav file is stretched so when I record 5s of audio I get a .wav that is ~10s+. Anyone have any idea why this might happen?

```
var mic = require('mic');

var micInstance = mic({
  rate: '48000',
  channels: '2'
});

var micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream();

var outputFileStream = new FileWriter('./test.wav', {
  sampleRate: 48000,
  channels: 2
});

micInputStream.pipe(outputFileStream);

micInstance.start();

setTimeout(function() {
  micInstance.stop();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that when I double the speed of the .wav file in an editing software it sounds perfect so for some reason it is literally stretching the audio

Answer (score 1):

**Conclusion** After doing more research it appears to just be a problem with mic given that many other packages that do the exact same thing work appropriately. Note that I used (Windows 10 / SoX 14.4.1). For those wondering what I ended up using instead [npmjs.com/package/node-audiorecorder](http://npmjs.com/package/node-audiorecorder)